# How to access connectionString in your model?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-core, debian, connection-string, dapper

How can i access the connectionString inside my model? I'm using Dapper. Most of the solutions i found were using EntityFramework and not Dapper.

**This is working on** my local machine (**macOS**):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    Dapper.DapperHelper.ConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"];
}
```

But **it doesn't work on Linux Debian**.

**The `Dapper.DapperHelper.ConnectionString` property is null on linux after i run the application.**

My appsettings.json file contents:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=ip; Database=db_name; User Id=my_user; Password=my_password; Pooling=false;" // SQL Server Authentication
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What bothers me is, that the same code works on macOS but doesn't work on Debian (linux).

Comment: 1. don't use statics, this beats the idea of having first-class DI in the first place 2. Make sure you also copy over your appsettings.json

Comment: I tried with non-static and it's the same. Also yes i copied over my appsetting.json (the whole "publish" directory).

Comment: And your appsettings.json really has that sections within it? Its typical to use user secrets (which uses a json file outside of the project folder, so it doesn't get commited to Versioning system accidentally)

Comment: I have added my appsettings.json file contents to my question. Yes, i opened the appsettings.json file on my linux machine and this is all in it.

Comment: So you are searching for "MyConnectionString" but you have a "RutarConnectionString" ?

Comment: No. Sorry, that was just a typo when i was removing the actual login credentials/etc. But i found the solution. Will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

In my Program.cs file I had to replace this:

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .UseStartup<Startup>()
                   .UseUrls("http://localhost:8888")
                   .Build();
}
```

with this:

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:8888")
            .Build();

}
```

which is the same as:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:8888")
                .Build();
}
```

List of using declarations:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Then it worked on Debian Linux as well as macOS.

This helped me figure it out: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-configuration-changes

But this part:

> WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder ASP.NET Core 2.0 offers a nice
>   convenience method for creating a very typical configuration for an
>   application.
>
> Instead of writing this:
>
> ...
>
> You can just write:
>
> ...

is not true for Debian Linux. This works only on macOS. Haven't tested it on Windows.

I also reported this as a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24446